# Usage of "Most meaning"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Is the usage of most meaning and most meaningful below correct?

> The day that has the most meaning for me is my birthday.
>
> The most meaningful day for me is my birthday.

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct and the same just that the first sentence expands the subject on general (more effect).

Similarly,

> I hate you. *— just hate*
>
> The person that I hate is you. *— emphasising the person is you*

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any grammatical error in either. The first one is correct but people prefer using the second one to the first because the second sentence is shorter and sounds better.